# Overcome the drawbacks of selenium in a web crawler

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I created a simple crawler. Starting from the root URL, the crawler will fetch the web pages and find other URLs to visit, called seeds, in this page. All the seeds found on this page will be added on its list of URLs to be visited. The crawler organises the links in two parts: ones to visit, and already visited ones. It will keep visiting the links until the list of links to be visited is empty.

On a website, the results are not always present on a single page, but are divided into multiple pages. Most of the websites do not have a link in the href attributes for next pages. Instead they are buttons, dynamic elements are used to induce a click and then the next page is loaded.

Similarly with filters. Suppose the homepage displays data for 2021 only,and I'd like to fetch links for 2019 data as well, but the source HTML of the webpage does not contain it. It require the selection of filters to be applied.

I tried to create selenium codes for different websites, but this doesn't seem like a scalable option.

Any suggestions or direction as to how I can improve my crawler, and make it more practical and scalable?

Comment: doesn't seem like a scalable option - I think Selenium can pretty much handle this situation, or can you do it from rest API ? or all of the URLs are known to you ?

Comment: I have the homepage URLs. Yes. I create a list of that manually. Rest I want that bot to crawl and fetch me links on that entire website. Selenium code needs high maintenance and is not generic. It is very specific meaning that the exact css selectors are needed to be provided to induce a click or an action. I can't scale that.

Comment: That's a skill to handle dynamic elements using css or any other locator. Is URL public ? Can we have some code whatever you have tried so far ?

Comment: the code works fine. I have no issues with the code. I want help with how to overcome the aforementioned problems I am facing while crawling.